# How can I (un)hide a SWT TableItem?

Tags: java, events, swt

I am trying to allow my user to search through a table of information, dynamically hiding/showing results that contain the search. I have the hiding part down, and it works well, but I'm having trouble showing the table item again once the search criteria is changed.

Here is my hide code:

```
searchField.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
                modified = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getItems().length; i++) {
                    if (!(table.getItem(i).getText(2)
                            .contains(searchField.getText()))) {
                        table.getItem(i).dispose();
                    }

                }
                if ("".equals(searchField.getText())) {
                    modified = false;
                                    //where I would want to un-hide items
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems you try to *hide* the `item` by calling `dispose()`. If you dispose a widget, it is gone for good. You cannot get it back.

If you want to *unhide* it again, will have to create a new item at the position of the previously hidden one with the same content.

Comment: Is there any way to hide the item, but not dispose of it?

Comment: @user1500452 No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to actually operate with some kind of a table model and JFace bindings, rather, then do it like that? And yes, disposing is not hiding. You should probably remove the item from the table.

Comment: Probably. I don't know much about SWT.

Comment: It might be worth of investigating it: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html. You might also want to use a Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably to save the data from `TableItem` into collection before you call `dispose`. Then when you search again you could check that collection and if matches are found, then insert back into `Table` by creating new `TableItem`.